# Mixing newrelic agents PHP + node

Tags: php, node.js, newrelic

I have an app whose backend mixes PHP and node.js.

I'm monitoring this app with newrelic, but even though both php and node agents are configured with the same appname, one of them appears as "appname (Node.js).

I tried using newrelic's API to push an alternate name for both agents (appname2). I restarted node before php5-fpm and my dashboard displayed "appname2" and "appname2 (PHP)".

At this moment I have 4 appnames onmy dashboard and I only need one. Has anyone made this kind of mix?

PS: part of the app was legacy php code when I took the project and I have gradually ported most of it to node. However, when it comes to using postgis, doctrine + spatial extensions do offer features that I haven't found in node.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, I contacted Newrelic's support and they told me that this can't be done.

It seems the transaction traces are unique per each client type, and I guess they're even stored separately, so it's not trivial to mix the traces from two clients on one dashboard.

Since you can set an alias for an app (which should be unique) you can rename your apps to have the same alias, but it won't mix them together of course. You'll just have a bunch of equally named apps, which on mouseover will display a tooltip saying "nodejs app" or "php app" or "sdk app", etc.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer about this anyway - it's something I had wondered about, so good to know.